# Display custom post type in hierarchical order with get_terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, hierarchical

How can I display a custom post type of products with a custom taxonomy (product category) in a list, in hierarchical order?

I'd like to get them in this order:

```
h3.parentcategory 1
  -h4.childcategory 1
    -li.product of childcategory 1
    -li.product of childcategory 1
  -h4.childcategory 2
    -li.product of childcategory 2
    -li.product of childcategory 2

h3.parentcategory 2
  -h4.childcategory 1 of parent 2
```

Unfortunately I can't wrap my head around the second level (childcategory 1 & 2). I'm using this code to display category and product:

```
$custom_terms = get_terms( 'productcategory' );
foreach ( $custom_terms as $custom_term ) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'productcategories',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $custom_term->slug,
                'orderby'  => 'term_group',
            ),
        ),
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<h3>' . $custom_term->name . '</h2>';
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            get_the_title();
        endwhile;
    }
}
```

I need help figuring out the nested levels of this list.

I'm editing this to try to clarify:
thanks so far for the help guys. and sorry for being a noob in posting...

What i'm trying to do is list products that are part of a subcategory, these subcategories can then be part of a big family (Maincategory). I'm trying to group subcategories under a Main category.

```
vegetables (Main)
  -tomatoes (sub)
     -red tomatoe sweet (product)
     -pink tomatoe sour (product)
  -cucumber (sub)
     -some kind of cucumber(product)

fruits (Main)
  -apple(sub)
     -sweet apple (product)
     -Golden delicious (product)
```

Comment: Are you trying to loop through all parent categories and list products per child category of each parent category?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `wp_reset_query`, instead call `wp_reset_postdata` inside the if statement at the very end of your loop

Comment: I would need to view the subchilds of the categories as well can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
$parent_terms = get_terms(
    'name_of_your_taxonomy',
    array(
        'parent' => 0, 
    )
);

foreach ( $parent_terms as $parent_term ) {

    $child_terms = get_terms(
        'name_of_your_taxonomy'
        array(
            'child_of' => $parent_term->term_id,
        )
    );
    
    foreach ( $child_terms as $child_term ) {
    
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'      => 'name_of_your_taxonomy',
                    'field'         => 'slug',
                    'terms'         => $child_term->slug,
                ),
            ),
        );
    
        $loop = new WP_Query($args);
        
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
                $loop->the_post();
            
                echo '<h3>' . $parent_term->name . '</h3>';
                echo '<h4>' . $parent_term->name . '</h4>';
                echo get_the_title();

            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        endif;
    }
}
```

Essentially what you're doing is:

1. Getting all parent terms;
2. Looping through the parent terms and getting the children of each term;
3. Looping through the children terms and getting posts associated with the child.

Comment: thank you very much! this kinda works, but it's not quite what I meant. i tried to edit my question for clarification.

Comment: `wp_reset_query` is for cleaning up after `query_posts` not `WP_Query`, this should be using `wp_reset_postdata`